# How to invite friends to my application via facebook iOS SDK and Graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm writing an iPhone application.

I want to give the user the option to invite friends to start using my application via Facebook.

More specifically I want to present a dialog that will let the user to select specific friends to invite.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157784/can-we-invite-people-to-use-our-app-or-send-friend-request-from-the-app-via-face/16605625#16605625

Answer (score 10):

It's simple you can just write the below code for personalised message and also you can easily select the friend's to whom the request should be sent, it's an straight forward and powerful method.

```
 [FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:NSLocalizedString(@"FBinviteMessage", nil)
 title:nil
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
];
```

Just add this six line of code to your Button action method, then the rest will be done by the IOS & FaceBook Inbuilt framework :)

Comment: nice, the best answer here :)

Comment: this seems to be deprecated due to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.9/class/FBWebDialogs/)

Comment: This is deprecated, What is the alternative solution for latest version?

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this:

```
Facebook* facebook = 
   [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"YOUR_FACEBOOK_APP_ID" andDelegate:self];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"My Title", @"title",
                                       @"Come check out my app.",  @"message",
                                       @"FACEBOOK_USER_ID", @"to",
                                       nil]; 

[facebook dialog:@"apprequests" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

You can see the list of possible parameters at this page (scroll down): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: thanks very useful. Is there any way to know on the code what where the invited friends?

Comment: I mean, how do I know on the code what where the users that the user has selected for the request, to keep the information in the app

Comment: hi i'm using a 3.1 facebook sdk. How can use this framework to send automatically request to other user to "try the application" ?

Comment: This is Deprecated now. They suggest you use the FBWebDialogs class instead. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBWebDialogs

Answer (score 6):

Today with the `3.11 version` of the facebook SDK you should use this in order to send an app request to a specific friend.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"YOUR_FRIEND_FACEBOOK_ID"
NSMutableDictionary* params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
NSString *title = @"TITLE";


FBSession *facebookSession = [PFFacebookUtils session]; //You may changed this if you are not using parse.com

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:facebookSession
                                              message:message
                                                title:title
                                           parameters:params handler:
 ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
 {

 }];
```

Answer (score 6):

Facebook SDK 4.0 introduced "App Invites for iOS".
Check it out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios

Comment: Any ideas on how to invite specific friends only using App-Invites?

Comment: @Marcio Klepacz: I follow the link i done in app it shows invited bt not received the invitation. Can you pls help me? I hope there is problem on applink creation bt cant find it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your facebook app id is same in both developer page and info in xcode next, enable sandbox mode and must fill canvas url [under app on facebook category] in developer page.

```
NSString *facebookID = @"Your friend facebook id";;
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:facebookID forKey:@"to"];

    NSString *message = @"SOME_MESSAGE";
    NSString *title = @"TITLE";

    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                  message:message
                title:title
                parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                        if (error)
                    {
                    // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                        NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                    {
                    // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                        NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Request Sent. %@", params);
                    }
        }}];
```

Answer (score 0):

To send facebook app invites, you need to first add details of your app here..  https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

In Swift 2.2, XCode 7.3 and FBSDK 4.1

1. `import FBSDKShareKit` `import FBSDKCoreKit` `import FBSDKLoginKit`
2. Add `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` with your ViewController class.

   ```
   func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
       print("Initiation sent")

   }
   func appInviteDialog(appInviteDialog: FBSDKAppInviteDialog!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
       print("\(error)")
   }
   ```
3. ```
       let content = FBSDKAppInviteContent();
       content.appLinkURL = NSURL(string: "fb link that you get in above developers facebook url"); //"https:// fb.me/1775107252721102" in my case
       FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: self);
   ```

Answer (score -2):

You can either use the share dialog to share the Link to download the app to the user's wall, or write custom UI elements and use API Calls to build your own sharing module. Trying using a Facebook iOS SDK to simplify the process or you will have a lot of work to do.

Answer (score -2):

```
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE"
 title:nil
 parameters:nil
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             // User clicked the "x" icon
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             // Handle the send request callback
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 // User clicked the Cancel button
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // User clicked the Send button
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
             }
         }
     }
}];
```